# fatfree framework: set variables on ONERROR

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How i can set variables in error function?

```
$f3->set('ONERROR',function($f3){
    echo \Template::instance()->render('layout.htm');
});
```

This is my code, and i need to add a similar thing

```
$f3->set('ONERROR',function($f3){
        $f3->set('page_title','Error on page');
        $f3->set('page_description','No description');
        echo \Template::instance()->render('layout.htm');
});
```

I did try with $this->set and $f3->set but without success in both of case. Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks good. What makes you say that `$f3->set` didn't work?

Comment: I get error 500 and a blank page. And 1.000.000 error row in apache log...

Comment: @xfra35 i.e. it was all ok.... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK... i forgot a simple variable... argh!

Please pay attention that in F3 all variables been initialized or not empty.